# Part of UserFrom Combox items text is not showing when clicking on dropdown button

Tags: vba, combobox, userform

I have a combobox with a list of Right-To-Left language Items. As it appears in the picture my problem is that when I click on combobox drop-down button almost 2 first letters of each item is not showing.

[image]

Comment: You could try making it a multicolumn combobox with an empty hidden column on the right?

Comment: @braX it seems the only possible way. I searched about how to adjust a combobox with and I found I can modify it with something like `ComboBox1.ColumnWidtsh=(";1cm")`. Am I correct? But doing so makes the first column width way too bigger than 1 centimeter

Comment: When i use `ColumnWidths` I typically do not specify a unit: `ComboBox1.ColumnWidths = "1;1"` as then it uses `points`.